# Making a subquery with a count

Tags: doctrine-orm, query-builder

I do this request in my repository:

```php
public function QB_findByGetNoTeamInFormat($idClub, $format) {
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
    $expr = $query->expr();

    $andModule = $expr->andx();
    $andModule->add('p.id_team is not empty');
    $andModule->add($expr->neq('t.format', ':format'));

    $orModule = $expr->orx();
    $orModule->add('p.id_team is empty');
    $orModule->add($andModule);


    return $query
        ->leftJoin('p.id_team', 't')
        ->where($orModule)
        ->andWhere('p.id_club = :idClub')
        ->setParameter('idClub', $idClub)
        ->setParameter('format', $format);
}
```

That give me this SQL request:

```sql
SELECT 
  p0_.id AS id_0, 
  p0_.firstname AS firstname_1, 
  p0_.lastname AS lastname_2, 
  p0_.email AS email_3, 
  p0_.id_club_id AS id_club_id_4 
FROM 
  player p0_ 
  LEFT JOIN player_team p2_ ON p0_.id = p2_.player_id 
  LEFT JOIN team t1_ ON t1_.id = p2_.team_id 
WHERE 
  (
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM player_team p3_ WHERE p3_.player_id = p0_.id) = 0 
    OR (
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM player_team p3_ WHERE p3_.player_id = p0_.id) > 0 
      AND t1_.format <> ?
    )
  ) 
  AND p0_.id_club_id = ?
```

But it's not the request that I want.
In reality I want this request:

```sql
SELECT p0_.id AS id_0, p0_.firstname AS firstname_1, p0_.lastname AS lastname_2, p0_.email AS email_3, p0_.id_club_id AS id_club_id_4, p2_.*
FROM player p0_ 
LEFT JOIN player_team p2_ ON p0_.id = p2_.player_id
WHERE (
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM player_team p3_ WHERE p3_.player_id = p0_.id) = 0 
    OR (
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM player_team p3_ 
            LEFT JOIN team t2_ ON t2_.id = p3_.team_id 
            WHERE p3_.player_id = p0_.id
            AND t2_.format <> '6x6'
        ) < 0 
    )
) 
AND p0_.id_club_id = '1'
```

But I don't know how change my function to get this SQL request.
I try to change that 
`$andModule->add('p.id_team is not empty');`
with a subquery, but I don't success to do it.

Comment: Why use the query builder? Why not simply write the query by hand, if you already know what query you want to build? What advantage to you get from tom QB on this use-case?

Comment: Hello @Yivi

I try to learn.
I don't know how write this SQL query in DQL, to use it in a createQuery();
I don't know how translate the "FROM player_team" in DQL.
player_team is my reltion table between the entity Team and Player

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I found an other way to do the request that i want.

```
 public function QB_findByGetNoTeamInFormat($idClub, $format) {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
        $expr = $query->expr();

        $q2 = $this->createQueryBuilder('p2')
            ->select('p2.id')
            ->join('p2.id_team', 't')
            ->where('t.format = :format');

        $orModule = $expr->orx();
        $orModule->add('p.id_team is empty');
        $orModule->add($expr->notIn('p.id', $q2->getDQL()));


        return $query
            ->where($orModule)
            ->andWhere('p.id_club = :idClub')
            ->setParameter('idClub', $idClub)
            ->setParameter('format', $format);
    }
```